# Cufon Hover Problems

Tags: html, cufon

I am having troubles making gradient color change for the cufon (on hover).
It works fine as for (non-hover) but (on-hover) it doesnt change the gradient color.
I will appreciate if anyone can help me ?

***Cufon part:***

```
    Cufon.replace('h1', {
    color: '-linear-gradient(white, black)',
    fontFamily: 'Scriptina',
    textShadow: '1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
});
Cufon.replace('#nav a', {
    hover: true
});
Cufon('#content h2', {
    color: '-linear-gradient(#b7dded, 0.2=#70ceef, 0.5=#20b4e2, #b1dbeb)',
    hover: {
        textShadow: '2px 2px red',
        color: '-linear-gradient(black, white)'
    }
});
```

***From HTML:***

```
     <nav class="mid">
      <ul class="tabs">
           <li>
                <a href="#" class="defaulttab" rel="tabs1">
                     <div class="lineRight">
                          <h5>TEXT 1</h5>
                          <p>Sub-Text1</p>
                     </div>
                </a>
           </li>
           <li>
                <a href="#" rel="tabs2">
                     <div class="lineMiddle">
                          <h5>TEXT 2</h5>
                          <p>Sub-Text2</p>
                     </div>
                </a>
           </li>
           <li>
                <a href="#" rel="tabs3">
                     <div class="lineMiddle ook">
                          <h5>TEXT 3</h5>
                          <p>Sub-Text3</p>
                     </div>
                </a>
           </li>
           <li>
                <a href="#" rel="tabs4">
                     <div class="lineLeft">
                          <h5>TEXT 4</h5>
                          <p>Sub-Text4</p>
                     </div>
                </a>
           </li>
      </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i know cufon hover works only on links.
you may use something like this

```
Cufon.replace('h1', { fontFamily: 'yourfont' });
Cufon('#yourid a', {
hover: {
color: 'green'
}
});
```

your html would look like this

```
<a href="#">
<h5>h5 text</h5>
<p>some text</p>
</a>
```

that would work ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from the spec (https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Styling), you need to explicitly enable hover:

```
Cufon.replace('h1', {
    hover: true
});
```

With that said, why not just use `@font-face`?